# How to export/generate data without copying its primary key?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got the following problem: I have 2 databases, let's say `DB1` and `DB2`.
I'm using SQL Server 2008R2

In `DB1` I have:

**tblPerson**

```
   ID Value
   1  Jake
   2  Sandra
```

In `DB2` I have:

```
   ID   Value
   1    Jef
   2    Kendra
```

I want to export or generate script or use a tool to become next.

In `DB1`:

```
   ID  Value
   1   Jake
   2   Sandra
   3   Jef
   4   Kendra
```

But I always get this result:

```
   ID   Value
   1    Jake
   2    Sandra
   1    Jef
   2    Kendra
```

I tried:

- Export (with property identity insert on)
- Generate script with generate primary key off

None of these worked is there a tool for this or is it just not possible and do I have to do everything by hand?

Comment: What happened to Sandra?

Comment: Didn't notice copy paste fault ty ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're unfortunately not saying which **version** of SQL Server you're using - if you're on SQL Server **2005 or newer**, you could use something like this:

```
;WITH CombinedData AS
(
    SELECT DBNr = 1, ID, Value
    FROM DB1.dbo.tblPerson

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DBNr = 2, ID, Value
    FROM DB2.dbo.tblPerson
)
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DBNr, ID) AS 'NewID',
    Value
FROM 
    CombinedData
```

That would give you an output something like this:

```
NewID  PersonName
  1     Jake
  2     Sandra
  3     Jef
  4     Kendra
```

Comment: The problem I got is I got 2 equal DB's in different productions. So they the data isn't equal to eachother. Now I want the data from one DB to complement data of the other. but I got dependencies etc etc... so I have to search for a migration tool or do it by hand as in my question and with these examples it's gonna be tough

Comment: @daageu: if you can export/import the data from one of the databases to the same server where the second database is located, then you could use my approach outlined above. Is that a possibility??

Answer (score 1):

1. BCP OUT the values of the table
2. BCP IN but don't use `-E` option

This will auto generate the key **only** if the key is [identity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933196%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).

---

**Or, simply do this:**

```
insert into DB1..tblPerson
select Value from DB2..tblPerson
```

Comment: The problem I got is I got 2 equal DB's in different productions. So they the data isn't equal to eachother. Now I want the data from one DB to complement data of the other. but I got dependencies etc etc... so I have to search for a migration tool or do it by hand as in my question and with these examples it's gonna be tough

Answer (score 1):

with the new table having its id set to auto-identity, you should be able to do the following:

```
insert into db1.NewTable ( Value ) select Value from db1.Table
insert into db1.NewTable ( Value ) select Value from db2.Table
```